# Char datatype in relationship entity framework problem

Tags: entity-framework

I have a 3rd party database where the primary key is a char datatype. When I run my query, I use an include to include the child table.  The count is zero though.  I look at sql profiler and results are returned.  The only thing I can see is an issue with the relationship columns being char.  Any solution for this?

Comment: Could you show the entity model and the query. Char keys shouldn't be a problem by themselves.

Comment: I have a table, License.  The primary key is License_Number which is a char (30).  The child table is License_Item that has a relationship established with it's License_Number field.  The Entity license has a navigation property called LicenseItems in a one to many relationship.

from l in context.License.Include("LicenseItems") where l.License_Number == "1234" select l;  Will return a license, the license items are loaded, but the count is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the Char type. "1234      " != "1234"! The DB may not notice this, but the EF does.

Comment: The records returned from the database is what is in the database though, right?  Even though the query may ask for 1234, the results returned from the query are "1234    " for the parent and "1234    " from the child, right?

Comment: Depends on your DB, I guess. SQL Standard says include the spaces. (As opposed to VARCHAR, which doesn't require them.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. If I use in my query to select from the child and include the parent, get the first child in the list, then get a reference to the parent, I am able to get the parent with all the child.

```
            var query = from l in Context.LicenseItems
                        .Include("License")
```

Comment: Char is a red herring, then. Here's the actual issue you're dealing with: http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx